# Conditional Summing in SQL with special output

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a SQL select statement but got some problems with it. Maybe someone can help out. My table looks something like this:

| Article | Name | Amount | Location | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0 | Name0 | 10 | 99 | 1 |
| A0 | Name0 | 50 | 44 | 1 |
| A0 | Name0 | 20 | 44 | 1 |
| A1 | Name1 | 300 | 44 | 1 |
| A1 | Name1 | 250 | 110 | 1 |
| A2 | Name2 | 10 | 99 | 0 |
| A3 | Name3 | 20 | 1000 | 1 |
| A4 | Name4 | NULL | NULL | 1 |

I need to do a select statement that will sum up the amount per article in certain locations, if count = 1. My idea was to do something like this:

```
SELECT article, name, sum(amount), location
FROM test
WHERE count = 1
  AND (location IN (44, 99)
  OR location IS NULL)
GROUP BY article, name, location;
```

This will result in something like this:

| ARTICLE | NAME | SUM(AMOUNT) | LOCATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0 | Name0 | 70 | 44 |
| A0 | Name0 | 10 | 99 |
| A4 | Name4 | - | - |
| A1 | Name1 | 300 | 44 |

The only problem is, I would also need article A3 with an amount and location of 0 or NULL in the output table. So if there are no articles found in the location 44 or 99, the row must not be ommited and contains amount 0 and location 0. But if there are products in locations 99 or 44, there must not be a extra line with amount 0 and location 0.

Is this even possible with SQL? Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: Please explain the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `UNION` of two `SELECT` statements?

- 1st returns "normal" data (rows that satisfy conditions you mentioned; `count = 1` and `location is 44 or 99`)
- 2nd returns rows whose `count is 1`, but `location` doesn't match (`NOT EXISTS` clause)

Something like this:

```
SQL> select t.article, t.name, sum(t.amount) amount, t.location
  2  from test t
  3  where t.count = 1
  4    and t.location in (44, 99)
  5  group by t.article, t.name, t.location
  6  union all
  7  select t.article, t.name, sum(t.amount) amount, null
  8  from test t
  9  where t.count = 1
 10    and not exists (select null from test a
 11                    where a.name = t.name
 12                      and a.location in (44, 99)
 13                   )
 14  group by t.article, t.name, t.location
 15  order by article, name, location;

ARTICLE    NAME      AMOUNT   LOCATION
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
A0         Name0         70         44
A0         Name0         10         99
A1         Name1        300         44
A3         Name3         20
A4         Name4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT article, name,
       sum(case when count = 1 and (location in (44, 99) or location is null) then amount end),
       location
FROM test
GROUP BY article, name, location;
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but this would add lines like:


| A1      | Name1 | -           | 110      |

Since A1 is already listet this line shouldnot show up.